# Tutorial images for Really, Really, Really Easy Step-by-Step Digital Photography book

Tags: tutorial, file, photobooks

I took in the library a book by Gavin Hoole and Cheryl Smith "Really, Really, Really Easy Step-by-Step Digital Photography for Absolute Beginners of All Ages".

In the first chapter, the authors propose to download tutorial images accompanying the book. The website for the book is http://www.reallyeasycomputerbooks.com. However, this website is no longer active, and therefore, I cannot download these images from there.

Does somebody have these images? Could you share them with me, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It uses Picasa for photo editing (which has since been discontinued) you may want to focus your search on a new book vs investing time in this one, especially since the photo editing is seemingly what you are interested in.

Comment: Yeah, our university library has kinda old books on photography. And actually you can still download Picasa and install it. It was discontinued just recently.

Comment: I was not suggesting you can't still download and use Picasa. I was suggesting that for a beginner, learning about software that is no longer supported by its creator isn't the best idea. You would be better suited learning something that is current in my opinion. For example the user community that may need to help a beginner will likely start to die off.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, nobody here has downloaded the resources at that site, *and* kept them for the several years since the book was published in 2009.

The Wayback Machine (Internet Archive at archive.org) has the old homepage for the book ([archive of the site as of late November 2011](http://web.archive.org/web/20111013125846/http://www.reallyeasycomputerbooks.com/DigitalPhotography/index.html)). Unfortunately, direct links to the page containing the tutorial images to download don't seem to work — the direct URL just goes to the top-level page for the book's site (archived).

At the book's site, at the bottom of the page is a box of links. The 2nd link is "Download Images for Digital Photography Tutorials". Follow that link to get to the tutorial images (you'll have to download them individually).

Edit: There's only 6 sample images. I was just going to put them here in a thumbnail gallery. **However**, only the 1st sample image, IMG_001.jpg, was captured by Archive.org:

[image: Sample Image IMG_001: Rotate]

Comment: Thank you! Let's hope that somebody has all other images.

Comment: "Chances are, nobody here has downloaded the resources at that site, and kept them for the several years since the book was published in 2009." Why would you assume that? I've learned from experience never to underestimate what judicious internet searching and requests can turn up.

Comment: @osullic fair enough, the old chestnut about making assumptions and whatnot. Still, *probabilistically* speaking, the intersection of readers of this relatively low-selling booker series, and people who read it and downloaded and *kept* the 6 sample images, and my own completely assumption-based and subjective assessment of the contributors to this site... I think the Venn-diagram overlap of those sets is fairly small. I assume. =)